# The equivalence classes and their representatives

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, intuition, equivalence-relations

A relation on $\mathbb{R}^3 \backslash \{(0,0,0)\} $ is defined by $(a, b, c)\sim(d, e, f)$ if and
only if there is $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda > 0$, and $a=\lambda d$,
$b=\lambda e$ and $c=\lambda f$. Prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation and find a transversal for the relation that is geometrically pleasant.

I can show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. For the reflexivity, simmetry and transitivity to hold simultaneously, $\lambda$ should be 1, except if there's a mistake in my reasoning.

Now if $\lambda$ is indeed 1
that also implies that if $(a, b, c)\sim(d, e, f)$ then $a=d$,
$b=e$ and $c=f$, which means that every $(a, b, c)$ is related only to itself.

Now the transversal is apparently a sphere, but I don't see how that could be if every point represents its own equivalence class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I can show that ∼ is an equivalence relation. For the reflexivity, simmetry and transitivity to hold simultaneously, λ should be 1, except if there's a mistake in my reasoning."

No, $\lambda$ is arbitrary. For reflexivity, $\lambda=1$. But to prove symmetry, let $(a,b,c)=\lambda(x,y,z)$ for some $\lambda\ne 0$. Then $(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{\lambda}(a,b,c)$.
Thus $(a,b,c)\sim (x,y,z)$ implies $(x,y,z)\sim(a,b,c)$. Similar for transitivity.

The quotient set is the projective plane over the reals. A transversal is given by
$$\{(1,b,c)\mid b,c\in\Bbb R\}\cup \{(0,1,c)\mid c\in\Bbb R\}\cup \{(0,0,1)\}.$$
The points with first component 0 are the points at infinity.

Comment: The OP states: "For $\lambda>0$".  This answer seems to be for $\lambda \ne 0$.

Comment: It works also for $\lambda >0$. But then the transversal has ''twice'' as much elements.

Comment: Okay, thank you, but I'd need some further clarification. How so that for reflexivity $\lambda$ takes a certain value, but that value doesn't have to stay the same for the symmetry and transitivity? Also I thought that the definition of symmetry - if $x \sim y $ then $y \sim x$ - in this case means if $(a, b, c)= \lambda (d, e, f)$ then $(d, e, f)= \lambda (a, b, c)$. This question is similar to the above, but why can there be a certain value ($\lambda$) before $(d, e, f)$  in the first part of the if clause and a different one before $(a, b, c)$, specifically $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ in 2nd part?

Comment: The definition is as follows: $(a,b,c)\sim (x,y,z)$ if there exists $\lambda\ne 0$ (or $\lambda >0$) such that $(a,b,c) = \lambda(x,y,z)$. For reflexivity, you can choose $\lambda$ appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

Reflexive: $(a,b,c)=1\cdot(a,b,c)$, so $(a,b,c)\sim (a,b,c)$.

Symmetric: If $(a,b,c)\sim (d,e,f)$, then $\exists \lambda>0$ with $(a,b,c)=\lambda\cdot(d,e,f)$. Then$(d,e,f)=\frac{1}{\lambda}\cdot (a,b,c)$. So $(d,e,f)\sim (a,b,c).$.

Transitive: To you. (But it amounts to noting that the product of two positive values of $\lambda$ is again positive.)

Equivalence classes are rays (half lines) with endpoint at the origin. So the unit sphere (centered at the origin) indeed forms a transversal.

---

Edit: To be accurate: The origin referred to above as the endpoint of each ray is not included in each ray. (I.e., they are open rays.)